# Delphi 2010, installing a package that requires JCL

Tags: delphi, package, jedi-code-library

Okay. So I have Delphi 2010 installed.

It compiles/builds
JCL/packages/d14/jcl.dpk just fine

I then have another pakcage (not Jedi) that requires JCL. (I get error that it requires that package.)

I have tried adding the path to jcl140.bpl to its project options, but that does not help.

(I would preferably like to avoid running the JCL/JVCL installer again since I have the same versions of source code running on multiple computers.)

Comment: Please post the **exact** error message you're getting. (For future reference, please *always post the exact error or compiler message* - being specific is important when we can't see your code or your screen from here.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve this another way. I decided to run the Jedi JCL installer. (And then switch the source back to the old afterwards.) That created the otherwise missing jcl140.dcp file (I only had jcl140.dpk, jcl140.bpl etc. but could not create/find the .dcp one) This seems to work.